# nginx rewrite # character doesnt works urlencode

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, url-encoding, urldecode, nginx-location

I have a requirement to remove a # character from a url. I was testing it with the following configuration.

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/testing.example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name  testing.example.com;
        error_log    /var/log/nginx/testing.example.com.log debug;
        rewrite_log on;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/  =404;
                expires -1;
                add_header Pragma "no-cache";
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
                rewrite ^/\$/(.*)$   $scheme://testing.example.com/dollar.html redirect;
                rewrite ^/\#/(.*)$   $scheme://testing.example.com/hash.html redirect;
                rewrite ^/\&/(.*)$   $scheme://testing.example.com/ampersand.html redirect;
                rewrite ^/\=/(.*)$   $scheme://testing.example.com/equal.html redirect;
                rewrite ^/\</(.*)$   $scheme://testing.example.com/lessthan.html redirect;
                rewrite ^/\%/(.*)$   $scheme://testing.example.com/percentage.html redirect;
                rewrite ^/\^/(.*)$   $scheme://testing.example.com/caret.html redirect;
        }
}
```

In all these redirects 
    http://testing.example.com/#/something - it delivers the index.html (Incorrect rewrite expected to deliver hash.html)
    but http://testing.example.com/$/something rewrites to dollar.html (Correct)
        http://testing.example.com/&/something rewrites to ampersand.html (Correct)
        http://testing.example.com/=/something rewrites to equal.html (Correct)
        when I accees http://testing.example.com/#/something  the rewrite log it seems that the request is only to the "/"  instead of "/#/something"

```
    2017/01/12 09:44:57 [debug] 19270#0: *2 http script regex: "^/\$/(.*)$"
    2017/01/12 09:44:57 [notice] 19270#0: *2 "^/\$/(.*)$" does not match "/", client: 192.168.3.26, server: testing.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "testing.example.com"
    2017/01/12 09:44:57 [debug] 19270#0: *2 http script regex: "^/#/(.*)$"
    2017/01/12 09:44:57 [notice] 19270#0: *2 "^/#/(.*)$" does not match "/", client: 192.168.3.26, server: testing.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "testing.example.com"
    .....
```

I was thinking that this could be because of the url encoding of url unsafe character # by the browser. 
If I encode the # character and access http://testing.example.com/%23/something - this rewrites correctly to hash.html

Please advice

Comment: The `#` part of the URI (also referred to [as the fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax)) is not part of the URI sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks Richard,
   Yes the URL fragment part is not available in the server . So this requirement seems to be  not doable using a server side redirect.